# (Swift) Adding a UIView above a UITableViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableViewController`, and I'd like to place a UIView above it (not overtop/covering, just above) while keeping the navigation bar.

This is a good example of what I'm trying to achieve, except as I said I still want the nav bar: [image]

I'm doing this in Swift (3) and I'm doing it all programmatically (no storyboard).

This is what I have so far in my `UITableViewController`, I'm stuck when it comes to doing the constraints programmatically, I'm not exactly sure what I need:

```
// Create the view (add subview in viewDidLoad)

let topView: UIView = {
    let tv = UIView()
    tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return tv
}()

// Constraints (call in viewDidLoad)
func setupTopView() {
        //x, y, width, height constraints
        topView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        topView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        topView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)

}
```

Anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: Thanks @Sneak, this is what I ended up with:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerLabel = UILabel()
    let logoView = UIImageView()

    headerLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21)
    headerLabel.text = self.navigationItem.title
    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    logoView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90)
    let logo: UIImage = UIImage(named: self.navigationItem.title!)!
    logoView.image = logo

    view.addSubview(headerLabel)
    view.addSubview(logoView)

    return topView
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 175
}
```

Comment: you can use a regular` viewController` and a `tableView`, or add your view as a header to the current `tableView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the method [tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview)

And simply if you only have 1 section, just return your `UIView` in the method.

If you have multiple sections, only return the UIView for section 1.

[tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614855-tableview) how you set the height.

You can also do this by: `tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView`

Comment: Winner. Thanks, that was a lot easier than I was anticipating.

Comment: @d0xi45 Glad to help, Some people overcomplicate things :P

Comment: So now, if I want to add a label and image view centered in the header, would I do all that inside `viewForHeaderInSection`, or would I need to do create them and do the constraints outside, then add them as `view.addSubview` inside `viewForHeaderInSection`? Would you be able to post a simple example?

Comment: @d0xi45 You can run your code as usual in viewForHeaderSection, if you have a much more complicated UI, you can subclass the UIView and simple return your custom class the same. That way you can use XIB and AutoLayout with your custom UIView subclass. Check other questions / tutorials for how to subclass UIView with xib.

Comment: Cool - I have my label an image in there now, two concerns though: first, the subviews (label and image) move with the tableview when I scroll rather than staying put in the header. Is there a way to stop this? Also, just to clarify about the constraints (I'm trying to constrain the label and image in the center like in the example in my question), I'll just set up the constraints in the tableview controller like I did in my original question, and call that function inside `viewForHeaderInSection`?

Comment: @d0xi45 https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/1614754-init when you initialize your UITableViewController, set the style to Plain, will give you floating headers that stick to the top. Otherwise you must use a UIViewController and add the UIView as subview above the UITableView. Yes, but I recommend you use a XIB and AutoLayout as I said in the last comment, it makes it easier for you to autolayout via storyboard. otherwise you do inside viewForHeaderInSection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791577/adding-uibutton-to-uitableview-section-header

Answer (score 1):

You will have big difficulties doing this as you can't really access the root view of a UITableViewController. You should switch to a UIViewController with a tableView inside it, you can then add your topView as a subview of the root view of the controller and add your constraints.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController`.

That way you can just properly setup the entire view as you need to, by making the top banner `UIView` take up a certain amount of space at the top below the nav bar, and then position a `UITableView` below it, snapping with constraints to the bottom of that `UIView` and to the top of the bottom layout guide.

I'd also strongly recommend using Storyboard, because from my experience building an app with a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`, there's really nothing you can't do programmatically after setting things up visually in Storyboard. There's just a lot of code and advice online from people who do things entirely programmatically, but if you don't have some really specific reason for doing that, I recommend using Storyboard. In this case in particular, it'll really help you lay things out quickly and precisely with proper constraints.